# Is there any halachic basis for beating the aravot on dirt?

Tags: halacha, minhag, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, hoshana-rabbah

This Hoshana Rabba, the shul made everyone schlep outside to beat the aravot on open ground instead of the floor.

Is there a reason for doing this other than keeping the floor clean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh, Yalqut Yosef (Orahh Hayim 664:9) [states](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_31.html#HtmpReportNum0021_L2) (my translation):

> על פי דברי רבותינו המקובלים חובטים את בדי הערבה בקרקע עולם, ולא על רצפה. והטעם מבואר בתשובת הגאונים, על פי מה שאמרו במדרש לקח טוב, לולב דומה לשדרו של אדם, הדס דומה לעינים, ערבה דומה לפה, והאתרוג דומה ללב. ובהיות שעד יום הושענא רבה, ישראל מרבים במצוות, ואם היה בא השטן לקטרג כנגדם, היה מתבטל ע''י ריבוי המצות, אך מכאן ולהבא אנו רומזים בחביטת הערבה בקרקע, שכל פה שיקום עלינו לקטרג לא יוכל לנו, ויפול ארצה
>
> In the name of our teachers, the Qabbalists, we beat the *aravot* branches on the earthen soil and not on man-made flooring. And the reason for this is illuminated in the responsa of the Ge'onim as supported by the Midrash *Leqahh Tov*, which states that "[the] *Lulav* resembles a person's spine, the *hadas* the eyes, the *aravah* the mouth and the *etrog* the heart". And since, until Hosh'ana Rabbah, Yisra'el increases their fulfillment of commandments and, if the Satan were to speak out against them, he would be nullified by their increased fulfillment of the commandments; therefore, from here onward we suggest, through the beating of the *aravot*, that any mouth which comes to speak out against us will not succeed and will fall to the earth.